# SharePoint 2013 moving data to another server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, migration, content-database, content-migration

I have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise version. It is installed from last 3 years.

Topology as below

1. SQL01 (Clustered)
2. SQL02 (Clustered)
3. FE01 (load balance)
4. FE02 (load balance)
5. APP01
6. APP02

Now I got development server, which is just freshly installed with SQL Server 2012 & Windows 2012 R2. Now I am installing SharePoint 2013 and updating it to match the version of the Production Farm. It will remain single box farm.

**Now my question is if I backup Production Version which is multiple server and try restore on Development Server which is single box, will it work or do I have to do something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should work because it's not a matter of how many servers you have, if it's a single farm then you can migrate it to from a multi servers environment to your new single box environment by migrating the content databases.

Comment: So you mean I should only migrate content database or should I do back up by Central Admin and restore it to dev environment

Answer (score 1):

As you already get the answer but I would like to give my 2 cents. to avoid any unknown issue.

- Install and configure the SharePoint on Dev server( Version should match to prod)
- Create new service accounts and set the permission.
- Create new Web app (s)

  - Configure the authentication as in Production
  - Apply customization if any i.e Web.config change etc
  - configure the Object cache, Blob cache if it is in Prod
- Apply if any farm wide solutions
- create the new service application i.e search, UPA, MMS

Now
 - Backup Content Database from Prod SQL server
 - Move the backup to dev sql server and Restore it
 - Attach the database to web apps
 - Test

I would not go with the SharePoint central admin backup and restore, as it may cause alot of confusion in naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did already in following way. First I make backup from Production with Central Admin than I restore it to Development Environment then when I select back in development version that time I change manually database name, application server name and all configuration to development server. That makes us restore successfull